# Variance thresholding shows RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice

Tags: python, scikit-learn, variance

I have a dataframe of features and I'd like to remove low variance features. I used the following function to filter out low variance columns:

```
def variance_threshold_selector(data, threshold):

    selector = VarianceThreshold(threshold)
    selector.fit(data)

return data[data.columns[selector.get_support(indices=True)]]
```

And I got the following warning for different threshold values:

```
/anaconda3/envs/Observation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_variance_threshold.py:77: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice.
  self.variances_ = np.nanvar(X, axis=0)

/anaconda3/envs/Observation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_variance_threshold.py:88: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
  (self.variances_ <= self.threshold)):

/anaconda3/envs/Observation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_selection/_variance_threshold.py:99: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
```

What are these warnings and how can I resolve them?

Comment: Have you tried the `fit_transform`?

Comment: @Venkatachalam yes, and I got the same warning message.

Comment: can you create some reproducible example using `sklearn.datasets`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean of empty slice and Degrees of freedom <=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301112/mean-of-empty-slice-and-degrees-of-freedom-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301112/mean-of-empty-slice-and-degrees-of-freedom-0):

> RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice

occurs when you use the wrong shape

following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955158/what-might-be-the-cause-of-invalid-value-encountered-in-less-equal-in-numpy/34955622):

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal

hat's most likely happening because of a np.nan somewhere in the inputs involved

and following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651803/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-greater):

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

Your problem is caused by the NaN or Inf elements in your out_vec array